# PHP MYSQL output views

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP change the way data is displayed
for example

```
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td> DotNetFrameworkVersion </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['DotNetFrameworkVersion'] . "</td>";
echo"</tr>";
```

is displayed  like this:         DotNetFrameworkVersion  DF,1.1.4322,2.0.50727,3.0,4,4.0,

but I want it to look like this: DotNetFrameworkVersion  DF,
                                                         1.1.4322,
                                                         2.0.50727,
                                                         3.0,
                                                         4,
                                                         4.0,

any help but be greatly 
appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If it's comma delimated values you could just do something like:

```
echo "<td>" . str_replace(",", ", ", $row['DotNetFrameworkVersion']) . "</td>";
```

Or am I over simplifying?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
str_replace(",", ", ", $row['DotNetFrameworkVersion']);
```

It replaces the comma with a comma followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to insert spaces after each comma?

You could try a string replace before it is echoed?

```
str_replace(',', ', ', $row['DotNetFrameworkVersion']);
```